# how to make a custom scheme url clickable in email?

Tags: android

how to make a custom scheme url clickable in email?  Now only http url is clickable.

for example:  client://blahblahblah  will not shown as clickable if I send this link to my email.  I want to make this link clickable in email.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what are you trying to do now, and what code segments are not working?

Comment: Some Android Email client does not support HTML emails, just to let you know.

Comment: yes  it is an HTML email.  Not only not shown as clickable on Android, but also it is not shown as clickable in gmail on Mac

Comment: Can you show us the HTML you are using? Why wouldn't something like <a href="client://blahblahblah">client://blahblahblah</a> work?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did anyone solve it?